# Error:Unknown host services.gradle.org. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle in android studio hedgehog?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am completely new to android.I have following questions:

1. When I create new project using empty activity, I could not run simple template because , I am getting Error:Unknown host services.gradle.org. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle".I tried all solution in stackoverflow.

2.Can I run android app offline  completely? If yes, why are so many host urls in setting and buliding cradles, are they communicating with internet?why this simple template asks to communicate internet proxy to run emulator?